# How to get nested div container height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two nested vertical layout containers each container can have a top and a bottom ratio content where the bottom one also has a nested splitter. How can I get the height of the middle one (number 3). BoundingClientRect gives the same height as the browser inspection which is not the visible height. See the attached pic. Here the top neighboring splitter height is also included. It also could be a question how to change this layout for getting right heights with the browser inspection?

```
    <style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .container {        
        background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.41);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .verticalContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .topContent {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .bottomContent {
        width: 100%;      
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .splitter  {
        background: rgba(31, 37, 37, 0.41);
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: n-resize;
    }                   
    </style>
    <div class="verticalContainer">    
        <div class="topContent" style="height:65%;">

            <!--nested container-->
            <div class="verticalContainer">

                <div class="topContent" style="height:65%;">        
                    <div class="container">2</div>        
                </div>

                <div class="bottomContent" style="height:35%;">        
                    <div class="splitter"></div>
                    <div class="container">3</div>        
                </div>

            </div>
            <!------------>

        </div>

        <div class="bottomContent" style="height:35%;">        
            <div class="splitter"></div>
            <div class="container">1</div>        
        </div>            
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: `Dom reference.offsetHeight`

Comment: i changed the tag to `<div id="div3" class="container">3</div>` and did `console.log(document.getElementById("div3").offsetHeight)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It might help you get height of container number 3

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  alert($(".verticalContainer .bottomContent .container").height());
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {        
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.41);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.verticalContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.topContent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bottomContent {
  width: 100%;      
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.splitter  {
  background: rgba(31, 37, 37, 0.41);
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: n-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="verticalContainer">    
  <div class="topContent" style="height:65%;">

    <!--nested container-->
    <div class="verticalContainer">

      <div class="topContent" style="height:65%;">        
        <div class="container">2</div>        
      </div>

      <div class="bottomContent" style="height:35%;">        
        <div class="splitter"></div>
        <div class="container" id="third">3</div>        
      </div>

    </div>
    <!------------>

  </div>

  <div class="bottomContent" style="height:35%;">        
    <div class="splitter"></div>
    <div class="container">1</div>        
  </div>            
</div>
```